# Can't zoom with Thinkpad T480s touchpad in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch, zooming

Zooming with a pinch gesture on the touchpad of my [Lenovo Thinkpad T480s](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t480s-type-20l7-20l8/documentation) does not work.  Does Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support it?

I tried [fusuma](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/blob/master/README.md) but it didn't help.

How may I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech"> /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'
```

Comment: if you run this command without thinking, like i did, and if your touchpad is sysnaptics, not elantech you will lose your touchpad. Re-run the command after replacing elantech with synaptics.